# How do I highlight the current line?

Tags: highlighting, hl-line-mode

I am obviously not well versed in the world of Emacs so I was watching Casey Muratori's Emacs video and whenever he traversed any file in Emacs, the **current** line always had a different background color to the rest of the file. I want that because the cursor alone is sometimes difficult to see especially when the screen is filled with code and all that. I want the entire line to be distinguishable. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely many ways to do this but the built in package called hl-line works very nicely.  M-x hl-line-mode works as a local minor mode. or M-x global-hl-line-mode works as a global mode. goto https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/hl-line.el to see more in the comments section.